# Does this invoke undefined behavior with linkage in C?

Tags: c, c99, undefined-behavior, linkage

From section (6.2.2/7) C99 Standard

> `7.` If, within a translation unit, the same identifier appears with
>   both internal and external linkage, the behavior is undefined.

While the following generates a compile time error due to conflict of definitions

```
// 'x' has external linkage
extern int x;

// Here, 'x' has internal linkage
static int x;
```

But the following compiles fine,

```
// 'x' has external linkage
extern int x;

void foo() {
  // Here, 'x' has internal linkage
  static int x;
}
```

Do both the cases invoke an undefined behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question stems from an incorrect assumption that a locally declared static variable has *internal* linkage. In reality a static variable declared in a block scope has *no linkage*. See 6.2.2/6

> **6** The following identifiers have no linkage: an identifier declared to
>   be anything other than an object or a function; an identifier declared
>   to be a function parameter; a block scope identifier for an object
>   declared without the storage-class specifier **extern**.

Only file-scope declaration can have external or internal linkage (plus local `extern` declarations).

Therefore 6.2.2/7 and your question simply do not apply.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I guess that's what happens when you copy and paste stuff around :S

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it doesn't, since the two variables aren't the same. The local variable takes priority over the global one, and in the scope of `foo()`, it's declared only once. See the assembler output - the compiler will most likely translate the two variables into two different symbols.